# Cannot display single entity on front-end

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-web-api, frontend, angular-ui-router

I am just building small ASP.NET WebAPI with Angular app which will be my portfolio project to my first work so I am begginer.

I faced problem when from list of products choosing single product then I am redirecting to product-detail component.
In DevTools/Console I see no errors and in Network the response (choosen product) is displayed.

I hope that I described my issue clearly.

Here is my code (sorry if there is too much):

- product-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { IProduct } from 'src/app/shared/models/product';
import { ShopService } from '../shop.service';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.scss']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  product: IProduct;
 
  constructor(private shopService: ShopService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadProduct();
  }
 
  loadProduct() {
    this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(product => {
      this.product = product;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

- product-details.component.html

```html
<div class="row" *ngIf="product">
    <div class="col-6">
        <img src="{{product.pictureUrl}}" alt="picture of product: {{product.name}}" class="img-fluid w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{product.price | currency}}</p>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle text-warning m-2" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 2em;"></i>
            <span class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 1.5em;">2</span>
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle text-info mx-2" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 2em;"></i>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg ms-4">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-12 ml-3">
            <h4>Description</h4>
            <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
 
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'shop', loadChildren: () => import('./shop/shop.module').then(mod => mod.ShopModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'HomeComponent', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

- shop-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ShopComponent } from './shop.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product-details/product-details.component';
 
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ShopComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: ProductDetailsComponent }
];
 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ShopRoutingModule { }
```

- shop.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IPagination } from '../shared/models/pagination';
import { IProduct } from '../shared/models/product';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ShopParams } from '../shared/models/shopParams';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShopService {
  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(shopParams: ShopParams) {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('Sorts', shopParams.sort);
   
    params = params.set('Page', shopParams.pageNumber.toString());
    params = params.set('PageSize', shopParams.pageSize.toString());

    return this.http.get<IPagination>(this.baseUrl + 'products', {observe: 'response', params})
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          return response.body;
        })
      );
  }  

  getProduct(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<IProduct>(this.baseUrl+ 'products/' + id);
  }
}
```

- product-item.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from 'src/app/shared/models/product';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-item',
  templateUrl: './product-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-item.component.scss']
})
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: IProduct;
  
  constructor() { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

- product-item.component.html

```html
<div class="card h-100 shadow-sm">
    <img src="{{product.pictureUrl}}" alt="{{product.name}}" routerLink="/shop/{{product.id}}" class="img-fluid bg-info item-img">
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column text-center">
        <a routerLink="/shop/{{product.id}}" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase">{{product.name}}</h6>
        </a>
        <span class="mb-2 text-center">{{product.price | currency}}</span>
 
        <div class="btn-group mt-auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-cart btn-outline-secondary fa fa-shopping-cart col-6"></button>
            <button routerLink="/shop/{{product.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary col-6">View</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of devtools]

I tried to investigate where is the problem (like typo or variable names).

Thank you in advance for help!

Edit:

Response for multiple results vs response for single Product:
[image: multiple results vs single]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **/** to the url

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //Routes...
  { path: '/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent }
];
```

just i advice you to :
try to seperate (check the id is exist or not )

in ngOnInit :

```
   const id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

in the function :

```
load(){
//check if id 
//do something 
}
```

Comment: Id of this product exists, you can see it on screenshot. I get correct response from API. After adding "/" to route I was redirect to HomeComponent. I think the route is correct because I am in redirected to correct component (ProductDetailsComponent ) but I don't know why any data isn't displayed?

Comment: In the image..click in the response icon near of headers ..verify the shape of data returned from api

Comment: I have updated these responses shapes.

Comment: I know that my code will be working for response which is not "wrapped" in data: { //properties }, but response where I get directly properties. I don't know yet what and where should I add/change in my code..

Comment: what happend if you delete the  *ngIf="product" and replace it with {{product | json }} ?

Comment: I got errer `core.mjs:6494 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{product' is not a valid attribute name.`
No results, nothing in response.

Comment: because u should write {{product | json }}..just to console the product in html to see what is the result or console the product in ts in the ngOnInit ..

Comment: Sorry, this is my product in ProductDetailsComponent.html  when I swapped *ngIf="product" with {{product | json }} :
`{ "data": { "id": 30, "name": "Product name", "shortDescription": "Very short description", "longDescription": "Very, very long desription", "category": 1, "price": 18.99, "imageUrl": "../assets/images/products/product.jpg", "stockLevel": 40, "orderDetails": [] }, "error": null }`

Comment: So to access to the id you should type product.data.id  ;the same for other attr...add the question mark if u need (like that product.data?.id) or in the subscribe this.product =product.data (more simple to repeat product.data.somthing).

Comment: Then I need to add property `data?: any;` to my IProduct, because currently doesn't exists (only in response from API)? Apologize for silly questions

Comment: No this data returned by the backend just do like I told you and will be ok (the question mark ? Just to check if data exist )

Comment: I did like this and it is working:
`loadProduct() {    this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe((product: any) => {
      this.product = product.data;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
`

Comment: So mark the response as ok ☺️ I am happy for you

Comment: Huge thanks, I knew that the solution is simple but not (yet) for me. Merci!